# Powershell Script to get all To and From addresses in Exchange 2010

Tags: powershell, exchange-server, exchange-server-2010

I am installing a new Barracuda spam appliance this weekend and would like to write a script to look through all of the mailboxes and export the From and To email addresses.  From there I plan to parse out the domains and create a base Whitelist for the spam appliance for those domains.

Is this even possible?

Comment: It's possible, but getting it from the Message Tracking Logs would be much simpler.

Comment: How does one go about that?

Comment: Run Get-MessageTrackingLog, and extract the addresses from the Sender and Recipients properties of the log entries.

Comment: I'm curious why you're spending money on a spam filter that you don't trust to filter spam by itself. Whether you put "@gmail.com" into an allowlist or a blocklist, it will be wrong. And if your customers/suppliers get email hijacking malware it will sail through because you whitelisted their domains.

Comment: It's just for a few key vendors.  I wouldn't do common domains such as Gmail or hotmail etc...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Run Get-MessageTrackingLog, and extract the addresses from the Sender and Recipients properties of the log entries